# verificar elementos não funciona

Tags: java

Quero fazer um metodo que vai verificar se um elemento já foi adicionado a uma lista, se já então vai incrementar 1. Esta é a classe que fiz, mas tá a dar erro.

```
public class Rascunho {

    private int [] vetor;
    private int countValor ;
    private int c = 0;

        public Rascunho () {
            vetor = new int [7];
            countValor = 0;
        }

        public void insertValor (int valor) {
            countValor ++;
            int i = 0; 
            vetor [i] = valor;
        }

        public int verificar () {
            for (int i = 0; i<countValor-1; i++)
                for (int j= 0; j < countValor; j++) {       
                    if (vetor[j+1] == vetor[i]) {c++;}
                }
            return c;
        }
    }
```

Comment: que erro está acontecendo?

Answer (score 0):

O método para inserir valor está inserindo sempre na posição 0.
O método para verificar, verifica mais de uma vez o mesmo valor.

```
   public void insertValor (int valor) {
        countValor ++;
        vetor [countValor-1] = valor;
    }

   public int verificar () {
        for (int i = 0; i<countValor-1; i++)
            for (int j = i+1; j < countValor; j++) {       
                if (vetor[j] == vetor[i]){
                    c++;
                }
            }
        return c;
    }
```